# When a website is too much for sqlite to handle?

Tags: database, sqlite, web

I'm curious, how do you judge when sqlite is not sufficient enough to handle data for a public website, and you realize it's time to use MySQL or something more robust? How do I know sqlite is enough?

Comment: Found exactly what I needed thanks to the answer below. Thanks. "Generally speaking, any site that gets fewer than 100K hits/day should work fine with SQLite. The 100K hits/day figure is a conservative estimate, not a hard upper bound. SQLite has been demonstrated to work with 10 times that amount of traffic."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

check here under the headring:

'Situations Where Another RDBMS May Work Better'